# How to retrieve a name (not a pull request number!) of my GitHub branch in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, git-branch, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I have the following problem.
I have a Jenkinsfile where I list the shared libraries I want to import in the following format:

```
@Library('my-shared-library1')
@Library('my-shared-library2@1.0')
@Library('my-shared-library3@my-branch-name')
```

I want to retrieve the name of the branches - in my case **1.0** and **my-branch-name** and store them in a separate variable. I tried to use the `env.GIT_BRANCH` and `env.BRANCH_NAME` methods for that, but they both return only the pull-request number of my pipeline (e.g., **PR-316** or **master**) but not a specific name of my branch.

In other words, is there a way to check whether something follows the **@** sign in the library name and return it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Assuming you are using multibranch pipeline. have you used `CHANGE_BRANCH`?